# WinSCP script file works in Windows 10 but not in Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, winscp

I want to automate really simple ftp transfers with WinSCP (Example script file shown below. The real file would handle many files, but all simple stuff.)

```
open ftp://username:password@ftp.site.com/
option confirm off
cd remotedirectory
get file.csv
close
exit
```

A batch file containing:

```
winscp.com /script="staging get.txt"
```

opens a command prompt window and executes correctly in Windows 10, but in Windows 7 the command window opens and then immediately closes, and no files are transferred. WinSCP is in the path in both environments. I assume that a parameter or command is missing from one or the other file, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: Enable logging with `/log=c:\path\to\winscp.log` and append a log from both systems.

Comment: Didn't think of that.  Hopefully, it will tell me what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for your suggestion. I saw the problem right away.

Comment: You are welcome. Either post your solution or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was making a couple of small syntax errors.  I couldn't see them because the command prompt window closed almost immediately, but the log file showed me what was happening and it was easy to fix.  The lesson is - always create a log file.